# Easy68k: View Initial values at addresses

Tags: 68000, easy68k

I am very new to Assembly programming. I am using Easy68k for Assembly.

Here is my script:

```
    ORG    $1000
START:                  ; first instruction of program

* Put program code here

    move.l  $00000080,d0
    move.l  $00000010,d1
    move.l  $00000020,d2
    move.l  $00000030,d3    
    move.l  $00000040,d4
    move.l  $00000050,d5
    move.l  $00000060,d6
    move.l  $00000070,d7


    SIMHALT             ; halt simulator

* Put variables and constants here

    END    START        ; last line of source
```

I just picked some random addresses to load data from, and I got the results:

d0=FFFFFFFF

d1=FFFFFFFF

d2=FFFFFFFF

d3=FFFFFFFF

d4=FFFFFFFF

d6=FFFFFFFF

d6=FFFFFFFF

d7=FFFFFFFF

My question is, how can I view all the data located on different memory addresses in the Easy68k and is the initial value always FFFFFFFF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy68k should have a simple window to watch memory contents: http://www.easy68k.com/tutorials.htm (Tutorial 4).

Note: Your code should *never ever* rely on memory having a specific initial value. The initial value of uninitialized memory is always machine specific, and in many cases *random*. If you need a memory area with specific content, initialize it in your program.